# ISO-8859-15 charset applying incorrectly in Weblogic but not Tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, encoding, weblogic, servlet-filters

I have a simple form submit request. Before the request is receiving to Servlet it is going through the Filter. In that Filter I am setting charset encoding as "**iso-8859-15**", because of this charset encoding the request parameter value is not encoding properly.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException {
        servletRequest.setCharacterEncoding("iso-8859-15");
```

For example, I have parameter value as “**1Depósito**” and is encoding wrongly to “**1DepÃ³sito**” instead of “**1Depósito**”. Because I have some international language special character (i.e. **"ó"**) in my request parameter value.

As per my google research, the input request encoding is **UTF-8** but in filter we are setting different encoding i.e. **iso-8859-15** hence it might be not encoding properly. But this issue we can see only when running in **WebLogic 10**. The same code is running fine when it run in spring-boot embedded Tomcat

**NOTE:**

1. If i set the character Encoding as **UTF-8** in my filter it is working fine even in WebLogic also but like to know how "iso-8859-15" encoding is working in Tomcat but not in Weblogic?
2. In both WebLogic & Tomcat the input request content type is same as shown below:

   - Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
3. Then why the **setCharacterEncoding** is failing only in WebLogic not in Tomcat?

Do we have any default encoding settings for spring-boot embedded Tomcat server?

How could I fix this issue in my WebLogic deployment?

Looking forward to your valuable inputs.

Thanks,
BSK

Comment: How are you configuring / applying this filter? The default encoding set through a pre-configured `CharacterEncodingFilter` is UTF-8 .

Comment: The filter is configured in my web.xml file which maps for all the requests (i.e. /*.*).  we didn't configured CharacterEncodingFilter

Comment: And that is your answer... Embedded tomcat doesn't do anything with `web.xml` so it uses the default configuration `CharacterEncodingFilter` and not your own filter. Also when using a `web.xml` with Spring Boot make sure you are using Spring Boot Legacy to properly bootstrap it. Or ditch it and use the proper way to bootstrap it as documented [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-weblogic).

Comment: You mean, if I configure the CharacterEncodingFilter in my web.xml will it fix the encoding issue when I run in WebLogic build?

Comment: Well yes, but I would suggest reading the documentation on how to properly start the spring boot application. As you are now basically running a differently configured application in dev and production.

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never.

> But this issue we can see only when running in WebLogic 10. The same code is running fine when it run in spring-boot embedded Tomcat

Web Logic either takes character set config from WebLogic Server System Property or from `weblogic.xml`

On the other hand Embedded Tomcat ignores `weblogic.xml`

**Fix**

Either provide character set in `weblogic.xml` or as WebLogic Server System Property.

- WebLogic Server System Property

```
-Dweblogic.webservice.i18n.charset=utf-8
```

- weblogic XML Config

```xml
    <charset-params>
        <input-charset>
            <resource-path>/*</resource-path>
            <java-charset-name>UTF-8</java-charset-name>
        </input-charset>
    </charset-params>
```

- Docs

[Internationalizing a WebLogic Web Service](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webserv/i18n.html)
[weblogic.xml - charset-params](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/weblogic_xml.htm#WBAPP615)