Oracle and weblogic have different encodings, is it possible to read strings without setting?
You are using Oracle 12c version (12.1.0.2.0),
weblogic is using version 12.2.1.2.0.
Oracle is using UTF-8 encoding
SELECT *''
  from nls_database_parameters
  where parameter = 'nls_characterset';

=> ALT32UTF8
and weblogic is popping up in euc-kr with the -Duser.language=ko option on server startup.
Since the encoding of weblogic and oracle is different, I think it is normal that all strings should be broken when weblogic reads data from oracle, but now the strings are being read without any problem.
I don't seem to have set anything in the db connection settings, is this normal?
Or could there be a part of the setup that I'm missing?
I'm using JSP model1.

It does not  matter if the database and the client use different character sets. ALT32UTF8 supports entire Unicode range, thus Korean characters are no problem. The key point is, that you tell the Oracle database which character set is used by the client. I am not so familiar with Java, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783902/odbcconnection-returning-chinese-characters-as/33790600#33790600 should give you an idea. Maybe this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43719223/iso-8859-15-charset-applying-incorrectly-in-weblogic-but-not-tomcat

nls_database_parameters does not apply much when you do use JDBC. No matter what internal encoding database uses, JDBC driver always return strings encoded in UTF16, which is the only native internal encoding of strings in Java.

@ibre5041 Then change the jdbc url to jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/administer?characterEncoding=utf8
Does this mean that writing it this way has no effect at all and it will always be encoded as UTF-16?

I'm not sure what this does? It looks like something proprietary to MySQL.
